# A question about bounds of an expression involving the Riemann zeta function

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta, upper-lower-bounds

I am interested in knowing whether the following statements are true for $t\in[0,\infty)$. If so, how do I prove them, or can you provide a reference?

$$\text{Re}\frac{\zeta \left(2 i t+2\right)}{\zeta (i t+1)}=O(1)$$

$$\text{Im}\frac{ \zeta \left(2 i t+2\right)}{\zeta (i t+1)}=O(1) $$

Comment: Please provide more context. How did you come up with that? Why is it important? What have you tried?

Comment: @Riemann This ratio appears in the Dirichlet series for the Louiville $\lambda$. There are a number of formulations of your hypothesis (RH) in terms of it, and other ancillary results, one of which I would understand better if I knew that the expressions above are bounded by a constant. If they were, then proving some of those equivalent formulations gets reduced to something simpler (which does not mean simple by any means). This is but a term in rather more elaborate expressions.  I cannot write the whole detail of it in a post here, apologies. I believe this is true and ought to be known?

Comment: @Riemann That is why this question is tagged as a reference request.

Comment: $1/10 \le |\zeta(2+it)| \le 2$ while $1/|\zeta(1+it)|$ is unbounded (there is $t_n \to \infty, 1/|\zeta(1+it_n)| >> \log \log t_n$) so the above cannot be true (technically it would follow that at least one of the relations cannot be true but I think that the proof in Titchmarsh of the unboundedness of $ 1/|\zeta(1+it)|$ can be adapted easily to show that both the above are unbounded)

Comment: @Conrad Thank you! I will look at Titchmarsh. What would be the order of the growth of $1/\zeta(1+it_n)$? And what is $t_n$? Are you using >> to say it grows at least as fast as $\log\log t_n$? I would be interested in an upper bound. Can we for example say if $1/\zeta(1+it_n)=O(\log n)$. I am ultimately interested in the value of an integral which contains these ratios, among other things, but I will leave that for another post. I thought I would start with this, which is more basic.

Comment: $t_n$ is just a sequence that grows to infinity on which $1/|\zeta(1+it_n)| >c \log \log t_n$ for some constant; it is known that $1/\zeta(1+it)=O(\log t/ \log \log t)$ though on RH the expected bound is just the one above so $O(\log \log t)$; this is in Titchmarsh too; not sure though if there are estimates for $t_n$ above on which $1/|\zeta(1+it_n)| >c \log \log t_n$, just that such exists (while $c$ above can be taken $6/\pi^2-\epsilon$)

Comment: @Conrad Thanks! I guess this is effectively an answer to the posted question. If you wish to write it as such, I will accept it right away.  If you prefer not to, I will edit the question to indicate that it has been answered as per these comments of yours.

Comment: @Conrad I wonder if I can ask you one more question, even if the original question is already answered. It would seem that $\text{Re}(\zeta(2+2it)/\zeta(1+it))>0$ in fact for $t>0$. Is this true?

Comment: Why would you think that to be true? I do not see any particular reason we cannot make $\zeta(1+it)$ close to a negative real

Comment: Actually it is known that the curve $\zeta(1+it)$ is dense in the plane (see Titchmarsh ch 11)

Comment: @Conrad Ok, I think I have managed to prove that it is true. It follows from w an observation of van de Lune plus my own figuring. I will add it to the answer I posted with your comments. This stuff is not very well known beyond what is in Titchmarsh, it seems.

Comment: @Conrad. Sorry no, I tried to edit the comment but was too late. I am missing part of the proof. I think I might post this as a different question. Thanks

Comment: Using $\Re \zeta(2+it) >c>0, |\Im \zeta(2+it)|<d$ and the density above its very easy to see that picking $t$ st $\zeta(1+it)$ is close enough to $-1$ one has that the real part of the ratio above is (up to a positive number) very close to $-\Re \zeta(2+2it)$ so is negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This questions are now answered as per Conrad's comments, which I copy paste here (I had to rewrite the texed parts, I hope I did not introduce any typos:

$1/10\le|\zeta(2+it)|\le 2$ while $1/|\zeta(1+it)|$ is unbounded (there is $t_n\rightarrow\infty$,$1/|\zeta(1+it_n)|>>\log \log t_n$) so the above cannot be true (technically it would follow that at least one of the relations cannot be true but I think that the proof in Titchmarsh of the unboundedness of $1/|\zeta(1+it)|$ can be adapted easily to show that both the above are unbounded) ...

$t_n$ is just a sequence that grows to infinity on which $1/|\zeta(1+it_n)|>c \log\log t_n$ for some constant; it is known that $1/\zeta(1+it)=O(\log t/\log\log t$) though on RH the expected bound is just the one above so $O(\log\log t)$; this is in Titchmarsh too; not sure though if there are estimates for $t_n$ above on which $1/|\zeta(1+it_n)|>c\log\log t_n$, just that such exists (while $c$ above can be taken $6/\pi^2−\epsilon$)